# What is a Limited Word™

Tags: pattern, word-property, computer-puzzle, computer-science

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Limited Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Limited Words™ | Not Limited Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TRAFFIC | DRIVING |
| MAILMAN | RANGER |
| BUFFALO | OSTRICH |
| COMMAND | CONTROL |
| TRY | FAIL |
| HANDLES | CLOCKS |
| DURABLE | COMPACT |
| CLIMATE | WEATHER |
| CAMPING | HUNTING |
| CHINESE | ENGLISH |

CSV version:

```
Limited Words™, Not Limited Words™
TRAFFIC,      DRIVING
MAILMAN,      RANGER
BUFFALO,      OSTRICH
COMMAND,      CONTROL
TRY,          FAIL
HANDLES,      CLOCKS
DURABLE,      COMPACT
CLIMATE,      WEATHER
CAMPING,      HUNTING
CHINESE,      ENGLISH
```

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

#### Notes:

- This puzzle can only be solved if the letters are in **uppercase**.
- This puzzle may involve some [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science) knowledge.

*Edit: Baker was changed to ranger, drawers was changed to clocks. All four of these words are **not** "Limited Words™".*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess:

> A limited word™ is a word that has the ASCII values of its letters adds up to some power of 2 minus 1.

Explanation:

> ASCII value of an uppercase letter = its A1Z26 + 64

For the Limited words™:

> TRAFFIC = 84 + 82 + 65 + 70 + 70 + 73 + 67 = 511 = **2**9 - 1** (same for other 511's)
>  MAILMAN = 77 + 65 + 73 + 76 + 77 + 65 + 78 = 511
>  BUFFALO = 66 + 85 + 70 + 70 + 65 + 76 + 79 = 511
>  COMMAND = 67 + 79 + 77 + 77 + 65 + 78 + 68 = 511
>  TRY = 84 + 82 + 89 = 255 = **2**8 - 1**
>  HANDLES = 72 + 65 + 78 + 68 + 76 + 69 + 83 = 511
>  DURABLE = 68 + 85 + 82 + 65 + 66 + 76 + 69 = 511
>  CLIMATE = 67 + 76 + 73 + 77 + 65 + 84 + 69 = 511
>  CAMPING = 67 + 65 + 77 + 80 + 73 + 78 + 71 = 511
>  CHINESE = 67 + 72 + 73 + 78 + 69 + 83 + 69 = 511

For the Non-Limited words™:

> DRIVING = 68 + 82 + 73 + 86 + 73 + 78 + 71 = 531
>  RANGER = 82 + 65 + 78 + 71 + 69 + 82 = 447
>  OSTRICH = 79 + 83 + 84 + 82 + 73 + 67 + 72 = 540
>  CONTROL = 67 + 79 + 78 + 84 + 82 + 79 + 76 = 545
>  FAIL = 70 + 65 + 73 + 76 = 284
>  CLOCKS = 67 + 76 + 79 + 67 + 75 + 83 = 447
>  COMPACT = 67 + 79 + 77 + 80 + 65 + 67 + 84 = 519
>  WEATHER = 87 + 69 + 65 + 84 + 72 + 69 + 82 = 528
>  HUNTING = 72 + 85 + 78 + 84 + 73 + 78 + 71 = 541
>  ENGLISH = 69 + 78 + 71 + 76 + 73 + 83 + 72 = 522
>  BAKER = 66 + 65 + 75 + 69 + 82 = 357
>  DRAWERS = 68 + 82 + 65 + 87 + 69 + 82 + 83 = 536

Answer (score 9):

A Limited Word™ is:

> A word that its letters add up to 63.

For example:

> climate = 3 + 12 + 9 + 13 + 1 + 20 + 5 = 63.

In detail:

> traffic = 20 + 18 + 1 + 6 + 6 + 9 + 3 = 63.
> mailman = 13 + 1 + 9 + 12 + 13 + 1 + 14 = 63.
> buffalo = 2 + 21 + 6 + 6 + 1 + 12 + 15 = 63.
> command = 3 + 15 + 13 + 13 + 1 + 14 + 4 = 63.
> try = 20 + 18 + 25 = 63.
> handles = 8 + 1 + 14 + 4 + 12 + 5 + 19 = 63.
> durable = 4 + 21 + 18 + 1 + 2 + 12 + 5 = 63.
> climate = 3 + 12 + 9 + 13 + 1 + 20 + 5 = 63.
> camping = 3 + 1 + 13 + 16 + 9 + 14 + 7 = 63.
> Chinese = 3 + 8 + 9 + 14 + 5 + 19 + 5 = 63.

Comment: You are not wrong, but this is not the rule I had in mind. +1 for getting this, but the puzzle will be fixed.

Comment: You can change the question and its data as many times you find it necessary, but if I were you I would have marked the answer as a right one and I would have created a new question.

Comment: I think that sounds reasonable and I should have done that right way. As I'm seeing your comment, naldjuno came across my intended solution. I hope it is fine with you if I accept naldjuno's answer since it goes into all of the detail of my intended rule.

Comment: Yeah, I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 5):

A Limited Word™ is one

> where the sum of the [ASCII codes of its letters](http://www.asciitable.com/) equals $2^k - 1$ for some integer $k$.

Example:

> TRAFFIC = 84 + 82 + 65 + 70 + 70 + 72 + 67 = 511 = 2<sup>9</sup> - 1
>  TRY = 84 + 82 + 89 = 255 = 2<sup>8</sup> - 1

Comment: @eyl327 ah, the [computer-science] hint made it easier. No wonder they have 3 or 7 letters ...